# Redirect To the log in page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have an ASP MVC 5 web site, i have several controllers and views, how can i redirect the user aromatically to the Log-In view if he is not authenticated without preceding all the actions by if(User.Identity.Is Authenticated)

Comment: Setup the FormsAuthentication. By default it might have already setup for you in your web.config. Then setup Authorize filter in global level

Comment: Have you looked into the RequiresAuthentication attribute? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.server.requiresauthenticationattribute%28v=vs.91%29.aspx

Comment: "Aromatically"?! Does HTML6 support odors? Which browsers implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Decorate your controllers (if you want all actions within that controller to require authentication) or specific actions with the `[Authorize]` attribute.  You can specify the login url the user gets redirected to in your `web.config` file.

```
[Authorize]
public class UserController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Must be authorized
    }

    public ActionResult Users()
    {
        // Must be authorized
    }
}    

public class ProductController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Doesn't require authorization
    }

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Products()
    {
        // Must be authorized
    }
}
```

**Further reading:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: thank youn but with your solution i'have to add [Authorize] before each controller, i want to do it just in one palce

Answer (score 0):

For this task you can make use of the [Authorize] attribute, which you can implement at either the Class or Action level:

```
[Authorize] 
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public AccountController () { . . . }

    public ActionResult Register() { . . . }

    public ActionResult Manage() { . . . }

    public ActionResult LogOff() { . . . }
. . .
}
```

In the above instance attempting to access any action method in the controller will redirect the user to the login page, after which a further redirection to the initially requested action will be made.

For further information on how to use the Autohorize attribute please see the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx), as it has expanded examples and background information.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1 :**

You can use inbuilt `[Authorize]` attribute in MVC..

```
 [Authorize] 
 public class YourController : Controller
 {
   public ActionResult YourAction()
   {

   }
 }
```

the `[Authorize]` attribute will check whether user is authenticated or not if not then it will redirect user to login page automatically

**Answer 2 :**

Or you can make your custom filter attribute as :

```
 [AuthoriseUser]
 public class YourController : Controller
 {
   public ActionResult YourAction()
   {

   }
 }

public class AuthoriseUserAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
   // Check user is authenticated 

   // if user is not authenticated then do as :

     filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new
     RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Login", action = "Index" }));
}
}
```

**Answer 3 :**

As you have said in your comments section that you don't want to write `[Authorize]` attribute on every controller in your project then below answer will help you :

```
public class YourController : Controller
{
  protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
    //....Check user authentication here           
  }
}

public class MyController : YourController 
{
  public ActionResult Myaction()
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

In above answer all you have to do is to make your custom base controller `YourController` and then you can put your authentication stuff there and then every controller in your web app will inherit `YourController`  instead of inbuilt base `Controller class`.

Comment: That what i did exactly, but i didn't use the OnActionExecuting method, i just decorate the base controller by Authorize attribute, and it works fine, but how can i move the Authorize attribute from a given action ?

Comment: @BilelChaouadi...if you want to authorize all actions of the controller then you have to use authorize attribute only one time at the top of your controller only...

Comment: @BilelChaouadi...i m not able to get that you are asking in above comment..could you plz elaborate what you want actually???

Answer (score 0):

You can use the events in the global.asax to authenticate and authorize on every request.

**Application_AuthenticateRequest**: Fired when the security module has established the current user's identity as valid. At this point, the user's credentials have been validated.

**Application_AuthorizeRequest**: Fired when the security module has verified that a user can access resources.

So, something like this (this isn't complete though)

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {

                // you can re-direct them for example
            }       
    }
```

Comment: That means we check just if the first user IsAuthenticated,if we have a Session_AuthenticateRequest event it'll be possible

Comment: Just the first user?  I'm pretty sure this will fire per user per request.